# How to create a flag for making of code starting after accept location

Tags: android, permissions, location

I want to start code after user accept my request for location

```
    @TargetApi(23)
public void checkLocationPermission() {
    if (getContext().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION);
    }
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "We need permissions for check available event", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


@OnClick(R.id.btn_refresh_events)
public void onRefreshClick() {
    checkLocationPermission();
    refreshingEvents.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mPresenter.refresh();
}
```

As you see i have the method for check permissions. But now my code run like doing everything on time. So when user accept request he must next time click the button for refresh events.

My question is how to make flag that

First i checkLocationPermission(), and if user accept permission thats my code:

```
 refreshingEvents.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mPresenter.refresh();
```

Run after this.

Please help and have a nice day! :)

Comment: Either let `checkLocationPermission` return a bool if the permission was granted by checking the permission again after asking for it or just check for permission in an `if` around `refreshingEvents.setVisibility(View.GONE); mPresenter.refresh();`

Comment: @TargetApi(23)
    public boolean checkLocationPermission() {
        if (getContext().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION);

        }
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "We need permissions for check available event", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return  true;
    }

Comment: something like this?

Comment: but this not work

Comment: Close, but you did not ask if it was successfull. See answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  @TargetApi(23) public boolean checkLocationPermission() { 
    boolean permission granted = false;
    if (getContext().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS‌​_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) { 
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION); 
        if(getContext().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS‌​_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            granted = true;
        }
    } 
    else{
        granted = true;
    }
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "We need permissions for check available event", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
   return granted; 
}
```

or

```
  @TargetApi(23) public boolean checkLocationPermission() { 
    while (getContext().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS‌​_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) { 
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION); 
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "We need permissions for check available event", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    }
   return true; 
 }
```

When you want to keep the program in a loop until the permission is granted (though I would not recommend that).
Then you need

```
@OnClick(R.id.btn_refresh_events)
public void onRefreshClick() {
    boolean isPermissionGranted = checkLocationPermission();
    if(isPermissionGranted){
        refreshingEvents.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mPresenter.refresh();
    }
}
```

Though there might be a more elegant way.

Comment: not working, i need click 2 times first for permission and second for running refresh

Comment: @andrey Do you want to keep asking until the permission is granted? I don't get your answer, does it not work at all or does it work when you grant the permission? Or do two windows pop up to ask for permission?

Comment: I move Toast to first IF for no copy it, At first clicked refresh button i having android alert for permission. Wheni click allow i just must next time click refreshbutton for refresh event, and then when i have permission i got refreshed content

Comment: That is strange because I can't find the source of this behaviour. Maybe you could see in debug mode if the program enters the inner `if` where `granted = true;`. If not you could try to change the statement in the inner if to `getContext().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS‌​_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED` and try again.

Comment: I try while, give me a secound, you helped me alot :)